# How to pass multiple "var url" in same function?

Tags: javascript, variables, var

so I did the below, looks like it's executing url1 fine but url2 is still not being applied. Individually they work fine, just not togeather.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Start() {
var url1 = "http://stream.xxx.net:7300/event/start";
var url2 = "http://stream.xxx.net:7301/event/start";
window.frames["ifrmInitLiveBroadcast"].location = url1;
window.frames["ifrmInitLiveBroadcast"].location = url2;
alert("Live Broadcast Started") 
}
function Stop() {
var url1 = "http://stream.xxx.net:7300/event/stop";
var url2 = "http://stream.xxx.net:7301/event/stop"; 
window.frames["ifrmInitLiveBroadcast"].location = url1;
window.frames["ifrmInitLiveBroadcast"].location = url2;
alert("Live Broadcast Terminated")
}
//-->
</script>
```

Here is the table code associated in the same script, maybe something here needs to be changed?

```
<table style="width: 400" cellspacing="1" class="style7">
<tr>
<td style="height: 50px; width: 200px; text-align: center">
<button onclick="Start()" style="height: 30">Start It</button>                                                                                                       <br>
<iframe name="ifrmInitLiveBroadcast" id="ifrmInitLiveBroadcast" src="" width="0" height="0" scrolling="0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</td>
<td style="height: 50px; text-align: center; width: 200px">
<button type="button" onclick="Stop()" style="height: 30px">Stop It</button><br>
<iframe name="ifrmInitLiveBroadcast" id="ifrmInitLiveBroadcast" src="" width="0" height="0" scrolling="0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your frames both appear to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many uniquely named variables as you like, example:

```
 var url1 = 'http:/site1.com'
 var url2 = 'http://site2.com'
 var url3 = 'http://site3.com'

 alert('Visit one of these sites: ' + url1 + ' ' + url2 + ' ' + url3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but make sure you have another frame / iframe named `myUniqueFrameIdentifier` in window.frames:

```
function Start() {
    var url1 = "http://xxx.yyy.com:7000/event/start";
    var url2 = "http://xxx.yyy.com:7000/event/startAgain";
    window.frames["ifrmInitLiveBroadcast"].location = url1;
    window.frames["myUniqueFrameIdentifier"].location = url2;
    alert("Event Started")
}
function Stop() {
    var url1 = "http://xxx.yyy.com:7002/event/stop";
    var url2 = "http://xxx.yyy.com:7000/event/stopAgain";
    window.frames["ifrmInitLiveBroadcast"].location = url1;
    window.frames["myUniqueFrameIdentifier"].location = url2;
    alert("Event Terminated")
}
```

Also, in your code you need to rename one of the iframes, id and/or name need to be unique:

```
<table style="width: 400" cellspacing="1" class="style7">
   <tr>
      <td style="height: 50px; width: 200px; text-align: center">
         <button onclick="Start()" style="height: 30">Start It</button>                                                                                                       <br>
         <iframe name="ifrmInitLiveBroadcast" id="ifrmInitLiveBroadcast" src="" width="0" height="0" scrolling="0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
      </td>
      <td style="height: 50px; text-align: center; width: 200px">
         <button type="button" onclick="Stop()" style="height: 30px">Stop It</button><br>
         <iframe name="myUniqueFrameIdentifier" id="myUniqueFrameIdentifier" src="" width="0" height="0" scrolling="0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this but something is still missing? I edited original question. Thanks!

Comment: @user3334034 Your iframes have the same name. See above